# Is my Fusion Drive set up on my iMac correct? or is there a fix?

Tags: imac, mojave, catalina, fusion-drive

I have a 2013 iMac previously running Mojave, now running Catalina. I thought on Catalina, that when in Internet Disk Recovery Mode, you should be able to select the Fusion Drive and be able to erase it. However ERASE is greyed out in Disk Utility when I select the Fusion Drive and is not accessible.**Is this the way it is suppose to be?**

I do have access to erase both the Container, the Macintosh HD and the Macintosh HD - Data, just not the physical drive or "Fusion Drive". **Is this iMac still functional and/or is there a way to fix it so the Fusion Drive itself can be erased?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Split the Fusion Drive (ssd & hdd)?

Answer (score 1):

Klanomath and all -

**Objective: Properly erase an iMac running Catalina built in 2013**

A functional computer should be able to be erased. I was trying to determine the viability of the computer>

Background: I needed to erase my iMac (running Catalina) with a Fusion Drive and was told that ERASE should be accessible while in Disk Utilities in Internet Recovery Mode. ERASE was not accessible on my iMac.

RESOLUTION:  My understanding is now that ERASE will NOT be accessible if a Mac has a Fusion Drive and is running Catalina in Disk Utilities in Internet Recovery Mode.

In the end, I could not use Apple's How to erase a disk (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496) documentation, but I can use the directions in Apple's How to split a Fusion Drive (using the Terminal) https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584. My understanding is the latter splits or fixes a split, erases and re-fuses the Fusion Drive.

As I can now erase the iMac using the How to split a fusion drive documentation, I have been told the computer is useable.

Side note:  I found and so did the people I was working with, the Apple Documentation to be confusing - it can be interpreted in a variety of ways and is not clear with respect to Fusion Drives and how to erase them.

If anyone sees an issue with what I wrote, please feel free to chime in.